# Why height: 0 can not work in css definition

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2

In my project, I use vue.js 2, and i have an `img` component.

Here is code of it:

```
<template>
<div class="banner">
  <img class="banner-img" :src="bannerImg"/>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'DetailBanner',
  props: {
    sightName: String,
    bannerImg: String,
    gallaryImgs: Array
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="stylus" scoped>
.banner
  position: relative
  overflow: hidden
  height: 0
  padding-bottom: 55%
  .banner-img
    width: 100%
```

The url of img is :

http://img1.qunarzz.com/sight/p0/201404/23/04b92c99462687fa1ba45c1b5ba4ad77.jpg_600x330_bf9c4904.jpg

Here i don't want to display this img, so i  set height:0 in CSS.

But unlucky, It fails. I have tested for removing height: 0, and it shows all the same.

why height: 0 can not work, who can help me?

Comment: give your img height: 100%

Comment: Or set it to "display: none;" if you want it completely hidden.

Comment: And then set 'display' to 'none' , `display:none`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take advantage of Vue.js and use `v-if` to show/hide your image as follow :

```
<template> 
 <div class="banner"  v-if="showImg">
     <img class="banner-img" :src="bannerImg"/>
    </div>
 </template>

<script>
   export default {
      name: 'DetailBanner',
      props: {
         sightName: String,
         bannerImg: String,
         gallaryImgs: Array
      },
      data(){
         return{
            showImg:false
             }
       }

  }
</script>
```

you could put `showImg` in your `props`, by this way you could change the image state using only Vue.js and avoid struggling with CSS